# Adding a dijit.Editor dynamical onClick

Tags: dojo

I want to add dijit.Editor after clicking on element.

```
    dojo.ready( function() {
    var handle = dojo.connect(dojo.byId("k"),"onclick", 
        function(){
            dojo.byId("k").innerHTML += 
                "<div data-dojo-type=\"dijit.Editor\" id=\"editor\" style=\"width:400px;min-height:100px;background-color:white;border-style:solid;border-width:1px\" > </div>";
                 dojo.disconnect(handle);
        }
    );
});
```

In general this code works but dijit.Editor is malformed, one cannot write in it and there are no default plugins. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this for inline editing ? Because if so, you should follow the examples on [this page](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/InlineEditBox.html).

Othewise, you should do something like [this](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/Editor#programmatic-example) rather than creating html in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I believe inlineEditBox is better fit to your need.
Also more generally, you add declarative code, in an onClick, after dojo.ready.
Basically it means that the html is "probably" parsed, then you get dojo.ready, do your connect, when the onClick happens, you add declarative markup in your html code, but you are not calling the parser.

I would recommand using programmatic approach for these kind of cases and keep declarative for templated widgets, or html string you will "parse" calling the parser.

Hope this also helps a little ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>function(ready, Editor, AlwaysShowToolbar, dom, query){
this.createEditor = function(){
    new Editor({
        height: '40px',},dom.byId('programmatic2'));autosave:false,
    query('#create2').orphan();

}
});

</script>
```

try this.. u might get a solution..

Comment: how exactly does this function ever get executed?